# New Motherboard, Atheros AR8161 not recognised. How to install drivers?

Tags: drivers

I just purchased a Gigabyte 78lmt-2sp with a Atheros AR8161. Ubuntu does not recognise the nic? how can I isntall the correct drivers with no internet connection. I have followed other tutorials on here with no luck...

Answer (score 0):

I think the driver should be in package linux-backports-modules-cw-*  where the * the the kernel which you can get from running

```
uname -r
```

Download the package on a computer with internet connectivity, put the .deb file onto a usb or cdrom, and read it on your new computer, so you can install it directly.